# ComboBox not showing text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have the following code that I'm trying to use to populate a ComboBox, but it's not showing the actual text of the objects that I'm adding.

```
internal partial class SortBox : UserControl {
    private Field[] FieldReferences
    ...
    internal Field[] Fields {
        ...
        set {
            this.FieldReferences = value;
            this.cboFields.Items.Clear();
            string NoneString = "(none)";
            this.cboFields.Items.Add(NoneString);
            this.cboFields.SelectedItem = NoneString;
            foreach (Field Field in this.FieldReferences) {
                MessageBox.Show(Field.ToString()); // <- This displays what I want displayed perfectly.
                this.cboFields.Items.Add(Field);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

public partial class Field : UserControl {
    protected string LabelValue;
    ...
    public override string ToString() {
        return this.LabelValue;
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting; they're all blank:

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Apparently, my Field class is inheriting from UserControl. I've done some tests, and it apparently has something to do with the fact that the class inherits from System.ComponentModel.Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your code right, you are trying to put a usercontrol inside a combobox.

Overriding the ToString won't work when you do that, so to make the code that you currently have work, just change the DrawMode:

This works:

```
cboFields.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
cboFields.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cboFields_DrawItem);

private void cboFields_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.DrawBackground();
  if (e.Index > -1)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(cboFields.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
}
```

But I have to say, I don't know if putting a UserControl inside a ComboBox collection is the best way to do this.  I would seriously consider refactoring that differently.

Comment: Just a couple of minor issues: this will only work if the DropDownStyle is DropDownList (which is what I needed anyway). Otherwise, the list will populate, but the actual selected item will be blank. Also, instead of `Brushes.Black` I used `new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)`. You get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

The items you add to the combo box should also be strings, just like in your message box.

Try: `this.cboFields.Items.Add(Field.ToString());`

Alternately, you can try setting the DisplayMember field, although ToString should already be the default:

`this.cboFields.DisplayMember = "ToString()"`

Comment: The problem with that solution is that `this.cboFields.SelectedItem` will return a string instead of a Field object. This won't work.

Comment: Hmn, interesting. According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx), the proper text should display as long as you're overriding ToString, which you've already done according to the previous line in your code sample. Try setting [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) as well?

Comment: "this.cboFields.SelectedItem will return a string..." => Hannele was advise the right solution and to have a Field Type you should create a new instance of Field;

Comment: @ARZ, I don't think that you understand what I'm trying to do at all. I want SelectedItem to return a Field, not a string.